# What's the right Fluent NHibernate ConventionBuilder for differing name on child-parent? for brownfield systems too

Tags: nhibernate, design-patterns, fluent-nhibernate

What code need to go here:

```
,ConventionBuilder.HasMany.Always(x => 
          x.Key.Column( /* what code need to go here? */ ))
```

---

Aside from making this...

```
public virtual Person Owner { get; set; }
```

...to(which is ideal only on greenfield systems):

```
public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
```

How can I prevent NHibernate from producing the extraneous Person_id in its DDL creation?

Note the **Person_id** was produced by NH(or FNH?) even there's already an owner_ref, and note the two references:

```
create table contact (contact_id int4 not null, 
                      number text, type text, owner_ref int4, 
                      Person_id int4, primary key (contact_id));
create table person (person_id int4 not null, person_name text not null, birthdate timestamp not null, primary key (person_id));
alter table contact 
      add constraint FK38B7242018FA494F 
      foreign key (owner_ref) references person;
alter table contact 
      add constraint FK38B724202B329A0D 
      foreign key (Person_id) references person;
```

I tried this just to make sure that it's feasible to prevent extraneous reference

```
,ConventionBuilder.HasMany.Always(x => x.Key.Column("owner_ref"))
```

Here's NHibernate DDL Creation when I add that ConventionBuilder:

```
create table contact (contact_id int4 not null, number text, type text, 
                      owner_ref int4, primary key (contact_id));
create table person (person_id int4 not null, person_name text not null, birthdate timestamp not null, primary key (person_id));
alter table contact 
      add constraint FK38B7242018FA494F 
      foreign key (owner_ref) references person;
```

**Note** there are no more Person_id field, and there's only one references now, which is correct. So it prevent duplicate references, it's possible, but what I still doesn't know is how to change the KeyColumn's name of the collection(IList<Contact>) under Person in **ConventionBuilder**

Another way is to just change the KeyColumn in ClassMap directly, prevents duplicate reference in contact table...

```
HasMany(x => x.Contacts).Inverse().KeyColumn("owner_ref");
```

..., achieved the same SQL as above, but it's better if I can make it automatic on ConventionBuilder.

How can I tell NHibernate from producing two references? Here's the mapping code (note this: **public virtual Person Owner { get; set; }**.  It's not **Person Person { get; set; }**

```
    public class Person
    {
        public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }

        public virtual string PersonName { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }     

        public virtual IList<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }


    public class Contact
    {
        public virtual Person Owner { get; set; }

        public virtual int ContactId { get; set; }      
        public virtual string Number { get; set; }      
        public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    }





    public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
    {
        public PersonMap()
        {       

            Id(x => x.PersonId);
            Map(x => x.PersonName).Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Birthdate).Not.Nullable();                   
            HasMany(x => x.Contacts).Inverse(); 
        }
    }



    public class ContactMap : ClassMap<Contact>
    {
        public ContactMap()
        {                   
            References(x => x.Owner);
            Id(x => x.ContactId).GeneratedBy.Sequence("contact_contact_id_seq");
            Map(x => x.Number);
            Map(x => x.Type);                           
        }

    }
```

What's the right ConventionBuilder on that design pattern("_ref" suffix for child table's field referencing parent table). That potentially happen on brownfield systems too.

Comment: Please reduce the information, especially code, to the minimum needed to explain the problem and show what you already tried. This is quite a lot to read. You could leave away all the other properties, a whole lot of generated sql etc. You'll get more answers if one could get the point in reasonable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found(formulated) the solution.  The key thing is we must setup the joining key on both ends of the entities, i.e. we must set it up on **ConventionBuilder.HasMany** and **ConventionBuilder.References**

The **ConventionBuilder.References** is a solved problem.  It is the **ConventionBuilder.HasMany.Always(x =>** that we need to come up with a way of traversing the referencing object(e.g. Owner) from the **.ConventionBuilder.HasMany.Always** code.

We must normalize the references based on Many-To-One mappings from **ConventionBuilder.HasMany**.  Unfortunately the **references** property is in **protected** access in ClassMap.  For this, we must **extend** the ClassMap, and use that extended class on our mappings, so we can traverse the **references**

Following is the solution I coded, check the code of NormalizeReference here: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/12/brownfield-system-problem-on-fluent.html

Comment: As far as I can see, you just take *ANY* of the references which points backwards and use it as inverse reference. You don't even have a tiny hint in the mapping of the reference in question, so it will do this for every reference in the class where this convention is used. **IMHO, this is a very very bad idea.** What when you have multiple references between these classes? It results in a unpredictable mapping. Worst of all: adding another property can break the existing mapping, which didn't change.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. +1 on your insight. For those *not-so-*corner-cases (i.e. no hint that can be deduce from the multiple references or object relations), the custom ConventionBuilder should just refuse(throw an exception) the normalization of references. I'll write the problem details on my blog and expound your idea in a more concrete terms. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Here's the new code that tackles the multiple/ambiguous reference  http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/12/intelligent-brownfield-mapping-system.html Usage details to follow

Answer (score 0):

You can't make it automatic. NH can't know that you want to use the same foreign key for the two references.

---

**EDIT** theoretical solution:

You need to pass the inverse property somehow, because this is the missing part.

```
ConventionBuilder
  .HasMany(x => x.Contacts)
  .KeyColumn(x => GetColumnNameOf((Contact c) => c.Owner));
```

I don't know how to implement it to get this syntax, but this is basically the information you need to pass. If you are lucky you can obtain the Type (`Contact`) by the compiler from the property you are mapping.

Ideally, you get it like this:

```
ConventionBuilder
  .HasMany(x => x.Contacts)
  .InverseOf(c => c.Owner));
```

Comment: I'm not yet sure if what I want is possible in FNH's ConventionBuilder. However, I'm sure it's possible with NH(explicit column name in XML mapping), and FNH if I'm explicit about the column names on ClassMaps. e.g. on PersonMap: **HasMany(x => x.Contacts).Inverse().KeyColumn("owner_ref");** on **ContactMap: References(x => x.Owner).Column("owner_ref");**

Comment: Well, it's not possible to make it automatic in NH, it has no concept of conventions/defaults. What I see in FNH is if *could* somehow setup those conventions/defaults in ConventionBuilder

Comment: There is a default: the property name. You can't put it in the convention build as you want it. There is an information missing: That the Contact's owner is always the Person which has the contact in its Contacts list. For you it's clear. But technically, it is absolutely not clear. You can have as many independent dependencies between two objects as you want. (eg. a contact could also have many observers, which are persons too) and nobody ever said that one reference is redundant to the other. You do this by mapping it to the same column.

Comment: I think I'm getting there, this: **ConventionBuilder.HasMany.Always(x => x.Key.Column(x.Member.Name));** yields **Contacts**. But still has many things missing, like what's the *singular type* of Contacts. Maybe I can start from there, if I can reflect the singular type of Contacts(i.e. Contact), then reflect Contact's properties and whatever matches the **x.Member.DeclaringType.Name** (yields Person), then I will use that reflected property(i.e. Owner) to make it as a name for **.Key.Column**: **("Owner" + "_ref").ToPostgresNamingConvention()**

Comment: What you need is the redundant reference. You can't just assume that some property that reference back is the inverse reference. You could think about passing it as a lambda. I Add another section.